# Connection to Redis Servier via StackExchange.Redis

Tags: asp.net, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I try to make a test project using the [Redis](https://redis.io) Server, installed on a Linux Ubuntu Virtual Machine, via a Virtual Box.

The Linux machine is linked with the local network via the Virtual Box's Bridged Adapter, the Virtual Box running on my development Windows 7 Machine.

The Linux Machine is a new one, just created, I did the

```
sudo ufw enable
```

and then restarted the redis server (on linux).

Now here is my try from Windows

```
C:\Users\my-user>nmap -p 6379 10.14.30.51
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at ...
Nmap scan report for 10.14.30.51
Host is up (0.0010s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
6379/tcp filtered redis
MAC Address: 08:00:27:98:94:49 (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)
```

I created a new .NET MVC project with my Visual Studio 2017, and here is the controller's code:

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RedisClient.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public struct Server {
            public const string IP = "10.14.30.51";
            public const int Port = 6379;
        }

        public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }

        public ActionResult About()
        {            
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = 
                ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{Server.IP}:{Server.Port}"); 

            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            string value = "abcdefg";
            db.StringSet("mykey", value);
            value = db.StringGet("mykey");

            ViewBag.Message = $"The value is '{value}'";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact() { return View(); }
    }
}
```

So, when I click on the "About" link I obtain the following error on the `.Connect` line

> It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect
>   on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE,
>   origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago,
>   last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10
>   available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402

**--EDIT**

The output of

```
var log = new StringWriter();

ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
    $"{Server.IP}:{Server.Port},abortConnect=False", log);
var logOutput = log.ToString();
```

is the following:

```
10.14.30.51:6379,abortConnect=False

Connecting 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive...
BeginConnect: 10.14.30.51:6379
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.14.30.51:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=4,Max=8191)
Not all tasks completed cleanly (from ReconfigureAsync#1524, timeout 5000ms), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=8187,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 did not respond
Waiting for tiebreakers...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=8187,Min=4,Max=8191)
connection failed: 10.14.30.51:6379 (Subscription, UnableToConnect): UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
connection failed: 10.14.30.51:6379 (Interactive, UnableToConnect): UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=8187,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
No masters detected
10.14.30.51:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.14.30.51:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 2...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.14.30.51:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Not all tasks completed cleanly (from ReconfigureAsync#1524, timeout 5000ms), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 did not respond
Waiting for tiebreakers...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Not all tasks completed cleanly (from NominatePreferredMaster#1761, timeout 50ms), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 failed to nominate (WaitingForActivation)
No masters detected
10.14.30.51:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.14.30.51:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 1...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.14.30.51:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Not all tasks completed cleanly (from ReconfigureAsync#1524, timeout 5000ms), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=8186,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 did not respond
Waiting for tiebreakers...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=8186,Min=4,Max=8191)
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 10s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
No masters detected
10.14.30.51:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.14.30.51:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
Starting heartbeat...
```

==References

In my .csproj file I have, among others

```
<Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
...
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
...
<Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**The related [SuperUser question with another details is here](https://superuser.com/q/1435346/465922).**

Windows:
[image]

Linux:
[image]

Comment: @JakeGould, that is a networking, but also a Programming question, I can't agree... You can't close as off-topic because cross-posted, what kind of rule is that??

Comment: "10.14.30.51:6379 did not respond" - it can't see the server; check your firewall

Comment: @MarcGravell, is there a way from Windows to ping the Redis port on linux, to check the server is visible?

Comment: `telnet`, `o 10.14.30.51 6379` (note that the caret will typically go to the top of the screen *without* redrawing, so it can be hard to see that it has connected), `ping`  - you should see `+PONG`

Comment: or more simply, if you have the redis tools available: `redis-cli -h 10.14.30.51 -p 6379 ping`

Comment: you mean, I need to install redis on windows dev machine?

Comment: @Serge no, the first option I gave you only uses `telnet` - nothing redis-specific whatsoever, just a command-line socket terminal; but: if you're going to be doing non-trivial amounts of redis, it will *save you a lot of time* if you have the redis tools available; you can get windows builds [from choco](https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64), but personally I use WSL and the main linux redis distro *on Windows*; `redis-cli` is the default REPL tool for interacting with redis at the command-line

Comment: I installed the tools fron choco, from your link, I also updated the OP with the screen from the nmap command, and the "redis-cli... ping" command you gave me does nothing (no feedback), it seems the port is filtered by some unknow application, even on Windows, or on the Linux virtual machine... I disabled the firewall, probably should be a problem in another place...

Comment: @Serge until the *operating system* can connect, the *library* has no chance - so... sorry, you're going to have to get to the bottom of that, but it isn't a library issue until `redis-cli ... ping` *works*, and the library *doesn't*

Comment: yes, I understand, there should be some network problem... because (as I added a new screen in the OP), from the linux machine I have the PONG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank to [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/a/967036/312894) I were able to make communicate the host Windows and virtual Linux machines.

The steps I did:

**On the Redis Server (Linux) machine:**

1) `ss -tlnp 'sport == :6379'` if you find `127.0.0.1` or `::1` in these lines, you've should edit the redis.config file, comment the `bind 127.0.0.1 ::1` in the config file (if not already), and don't forget to **restart redis** after changing of the configuration.
If you see something like `0.0.0.0:6379`, follow the next step.

2) Check the `protected mode` of Redis in the same config file, if is enabled and you want to keep it, you can use `requirepass <yourConnectionPassToUseOnClientConnectionString>` in the Redis config file.

3) Check your client IP address (in my case the windows client computer).
Add it to the Linux `iptables`:

```
iptables -A INPUT --src <clientIpAddress> -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
```

3') in order to make this added entry *persistent*, see how to save the *iptables* state [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/373526).

**On the Client (Windows) machine:**

4) use the above password in the connection string to connect to the Linux Redis Server

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = 
  ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{Server.IP}:{Server.Port},resolvedns=1,abortConnect=False,password={Server.Password}");
```

5*) optionally, you can add the you can get Windows builds [from choco](https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64) (install it on Windows), to test the connection from the client Windows, using cmd

```
redis-cli -h <LinuxServerIP> -p 6379 ping
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better to ask [on the library github](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues); the question I'll ask *then* is: please do:

```cs
var log = new StringWriter();

ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
    $"{Server.IP}:{Server.Port},abortConnect=False", log);
var logOutput = log.ToString();
```

and tell us what `logOutput` is.

My guess is that either:

- there's no TCP access due to a firewall rule
- there's an assembly binding problem, often if you're using .NET Framework

The latter one is probably more likely, and the usual fix is to add **explicit** `<PackageReference>` references to:

- System.Buffers (>= 4.4.0)
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (>= 4.5.2)

i.e.

```cs
<PackageReference Include="System.Buffers" Version="4.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.5.2" />
```

and probably also (because ... reasons)

```cs
<PackageReference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" Version="4.5.0" />
```

Basically, nuget has some problems with transitive dependencies and the above *Microsoft* libraries. This is outside of my control.

Comment: actually I commented in the redis.conf the bind to 127.0.0. the error message changed to just "It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s)." I will do what you suggested and do a feedback

Comment: @Serge that doesn't open firewall holes, though

Comment: I did also "sudo ufw enable"

Comment: I suppose you are aware, more details (and the conf file) is in that SuperUser question of mine https://superuser.com/q/1435346/465922

Comment: @JakeGould what is the problem? On superUser I have a question on connection and ports between Linux and Windows Machines, that is a network one. Here, on SO, I have a programming question on how to enable the StackExchange.Redis component to connect to a Redis Server, that is a programming one.

Comment: @MarcGravell, the problem is solved, see my answer, thank you a lot for your time, the steps you provided helped me during the search of the answer!