# Azure Redis Cache using StackExchange,Redis get exception Could not parse host and port from

Tags: c#, .net, azure, redis

I am able to connect to a local Windows Docker Redis without issue however when I try the same using StackExchange.Redis, with an Azure Redis Cache as per this example ...

```
// Configure GraphQL Gateway Redis Cache
builder.Services.AddSingleton(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("mycompanyname.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=mypassword,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"));
```

I get the following exception ....

```
[mycompany-coreservices-meta-gw_821e1ce4-9]: Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Could not parse host and port from 'mycompanyname.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=mypassword,ssl=True,abortConnect=False' (Parameter 'hostAndPort')
[mycompany-coreservices-meta-gw_821e1ce4-9]: at StackExchange.Redis.EndPointCollection.Add(String hostAndPort) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/EndPointCollection.cs:line 46
[mycompany-coreservices-meta-gw_821e1ce4-9]: at MyCompany.CoreServices.Meta.Gateway.DependencyInjection.GraphQlConfiguration.AddGraphQLConfiguration(IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration) in E:\MyCompany\CoreServices\MetaModel\SQL\Gateway\DependencyInjection\GraphQlConfiguration.cs:line 25
[mycompany-coreservices-meta-gw_821e1ce4-9]: at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in E:\MyCompany\CoreServices\MetaModel\SQL\Gateway\Program.cs:line 38
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection to Redis Servier via StackExchange.Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080984/connection-to-redis-servier-via-stackexchange-redis)